# Adform API: totals mismatch when querying with dimension and without dimensions

Tags: facebook, api, google-analytics

I'm working on PHP application that retrieves data from Adform API every day and saves them to Database.
There is a problem that data queried using dimensions, for example date and banner do not match totals, retrieved without dimensions.

For example, I make a POST to https://api.adform.com/v1/reportingstats/agency/reportdata

```
{
    "metrics": ["ctr"],
    "dimensions": ["date", "banner"],
    "filter": {
        "date":{
            "from":"2016-08-01",
            "to":"2016-08-30"
        },
        "campaign":{
            "id":campaign_id
        }

    },
    "paging":{
        "page":1,
        "pageSize":10000
    }
}
```

Response is:

```
{
  "reportData": {
    "columnHeaders": [
      "date",
      "banner",
      "ctr"
    ],
    "columns": [
      {
        "key": "date"
      },
      {
        "key": "banner"
      },
      {
        "key": "ctr"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "2016-08-02T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.00816326530612245
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-03T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0024213075060532689
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-03T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.001207653432082372
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-04T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.003472222222222222
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-04T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000802886393241096
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-05T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-05T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000676782107058102
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-06T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-06T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000926995987708068
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-07T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.00904977375565611
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-07T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.0010050565441998231
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-08T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0022935779816513758
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-08T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000736000744868224
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-09T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0052219321148825066
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-09T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000636109173796044
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-10T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0057971014492753624
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-10T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000724849063441972
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-11T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-11T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000581557986484298
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-12T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0043103448275862068
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-12T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000671168239505369
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-13T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-13T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000803754549989838
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-14T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-14T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000989294421086104
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-15T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0.0064516129032258056
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-15T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000638244734480941
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-16T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000549180805298763
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-17T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000551568224222697
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-18T00:00:00",
        "banner_1",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-18T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000678091480705215
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-19T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-22T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000360310246085577
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-23T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000498299661680756
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-24T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000561990345005873
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-25T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000364882901395197
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-26T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000372206184069575
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-27T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000696784292763943
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-28T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.00084914217341799
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-29T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000441720501352769
      ],
      [
        "2016-08-30T00:00:00",
        "banner_2",
        0.000556096204643403
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

So, total average **CTR = 0.0015624820601283 = 0.15%**

When I query without any dimensions:

```
{
    "metrics": ["ctr"],
    "filter": {
        "date":{
            "from":"2016-08-01",
            "to":"2016-08-30"
        },
        "campaign":{
            "id":campaign_id
        }

    },
    "paging":{
        "page":1,
        "pageSize":10000
    }
}
```

I get:

```
{
  "reportData": {
    "columnHeaders": [
      "ctr"
    ],
    "columns": [
      {
        "key": "ctr"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        0.000729710843077063
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

**CTR = 0.000729710843077063 = 0.07%**

What is wrong? 
**Why such a difference: 0.15% vs 0.07%?**
May be I should count CTR not by simple AVG but another way?

I also spotted the same issue with other APIs, such as Google Analytics API and Facebook Marketing API. **Totals and averages counted locally using data sampled by dimensions are not always the same as totals provided by APIs themselves**.

Comment: search for `weighted average`